# What is the argument count limit to a function call?

Tags: elisp, emacs-internals

What is the argument count limit to a function call?

I think that `max-specpdl-size` is related to answer:

> This variable defines the limit on the total number of local variable
>   bindings and ‘unwind-protect’ cleanups that are allowed before Emacs
>   signals an error

but I don't think that `defun` makes local binding using `let`.

I try `(macroexpand-all '(defun my (x) (+ x 1))) C-u C-x e` and get:

```el
(defalias (quote my) (function (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
```

So I check `eval.c` for evaluator code:

```c
apply_lambda (Lisp_Object fun, Lisp_Object args, ptrdiff_t count) {
  EMACS_INT numargs;
  register Lisp_Object *arg_vector;

  numargs = XFASTINT (Flength (args));
  SAFE_ALLOCA_LISP (arg_vector, numargs);
  ...
```

which leads to `SAFE_ALLOCA_LISP`:

```c
#define SAFE_ALLOCA_LISP(buf, nelt)                            \
  do {                                                         \
    if ((nelt) <= lisp_word_count (sa_avail))                  \
      (buf) = AVAIL_ALLOCA ((nelt) * word_size);               \
    else if ((nelt) <= min (PTRDIFF_MAX, SIZE_MAX) / word_size) \
      {                                                        \
        Lisp_Object arg_;                                      \
        (buf) = xmalloc ((nelt) * word_size);                  \
        arg_ = make_save_memory (buf, nelt);                   \
        sa_must_free = true;                                   \
        record_unwind_protect (free_save_value, arg_);         \
      }                                                        \
    else                                                       \
      memory_full (SIZE_MAX);                                  \
  } while (false)
```

That piece is hard for me to understand… Rest of the code doesn't seem to
expose any restriction but I am unsure…

Compare with Common Lisp constants: [LAMBDA-PARAMETERS-LIMIT](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_lamb_1.htm) and
[CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use case? Why do you want to know the limit (if there is a definite one) - what will you use it for?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is limited only by amount of available memory. I couldn't find any information about this sort of limitation in official manual, so it generally means that number of arguments an Emacs Lisp function can take is not limited on language level, otherwise it would be explicitly mentioned.